# Exception when using Take in Entity Framework Core 3.1.10

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Here is the query I try to execute:

```
var contests = await _dbContext.Contests.Include(o => o.Winner)
                .Where(o=>o.Ended!=null)
                .Select(c => new 
                {
                    Contest = c,
                    Strings = _dbContext.ContestCountryStrings.Where(o=>o.ContestId==c.Id && (o.Country.Equals(language) || o.Country.Equals("Default"))).ToList()
                }).Take(3).ToListAsync();
```

And these are the entities:

```
[Table("Contests")]
public class Contest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime DueTo { get; set; }
    
    public uint DurationInHours { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Started { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Ended { get; set; }
    
    public int? WinnerId { get; set; }
    public User Winner { get; set; }
    
    public bool Recurrent { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContestCountryStrings")]
public class ContestCountryString
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContestId { get; set; }
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When executed I get an exception like this:

> fail:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: EF.Property called with wrong
> property name.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
> binaryExpression)    at
> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.MySqlSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
> binaryExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression
> expression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateExpression(Expression
> expression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.CreateJoinPredicate(Expression
> outerKey, Expression innerKey)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.CreateJoinPredicate(ShapedQueryExpression
> outer, LambdaExpression outerKeySelector, ShapedQueryExpression inner,
> LambdaExpression innerKeySelector)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateLeftJoin(ShapedQueryExpression
> outer, ShapedQueryExpression inner, LambdaExpression outerKeySelector,
> LambdaExpression innerKeySelector, LambdaExpression resultSelector)
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor)    at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression
> query)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression
> query, Boolean async)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase
> database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object
> cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MoneyAppBackend.Controllers.ContestsController._GetLas10PastEvents(EventType
> type, String language) in
> /Users/juanjoseduran/Documents/Development/Projects/dotnet/MoneyAppBackend/MoneyAppBackend/Controllers/ContestsController.cs:line
> 106    at
> MoneyAppBackend.Controllers.ContestsController.GetAll(EventType type,
> String lang, String uuid) in
> /Users/juanjoseduran/Documents/Development/Projects/dotnet/MoneyAppBackend/MoneyAppBackend/Controllers/ContestsController.cs:line
> 57    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

If I remove the Take call it works correctly.

Comment: What happens if you move the `Take` before the `Select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @NetMage said,Since the data you want to `take` is `Contest` type data, if you put the `take` after the `Select` is to operate on the data after the `Select`,The data obtained will not be of `Contest` type, it will cause an exception.

You can change your code like below:

```
var contests = await _dbContext.Contests.Include(o => o.Winner)
        .Where(o=>o.Ended!=null).Take(3)
        .Select(c => new 
        {
            Contest = c,
            Strings = _dbContext.ContestCountryStrings.Where(o=>o.ContestId==c.Id && (o.Country.Equals(language) || o.Country.Equals("Default"))).ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: wouldn't These 2 versions fetch all rows and then apply the filters? This is exactly what I am trying to avoid in my query. Thanks for the examples, but I would like to keep the fetching of rows to a minimum as in my query.

Comment: Why would it be a problem if the Take() was on the anonymous type? You can do a Take(3) on anonymous types, can't you?